# Cannot use console in Chrome Dev tools in the Chrome window controlled by selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I can use console in Chrome Dev Tools in a normal Chrome window to debug xpath like $x("//div") to debug the xpath.
But when Selenium-Chrome-Driver generates a Chrome window in C# SpecFlow, in this Chrome window, I cannot debug xpath in console by typing $x("//div"), the console reported error:

$x("//div")
VM1819:1 Uncaught TypeError: $x is not a function
    at :1:1

Already tried the following code to switch on some ChromeOptions, but got the same problem.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
string user_data_dir = settings.SelectSingleNode("//LoginEmail/ChromeUserDataDir").InnerText;
user_data_dir = String.Format(@"user-data-dir={0}", user_data_dir);
options.AddArgument(user_data_dir);
options.AddArgument(@"--enable-devtools-experiments");
options.AddArgument(@"--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. In a normal Chrome window accessing a website other than gmail, I can use Console in Chrome Dev Tools to debug xpath, in a Chrome window accessing gmail, I cannot use Console to debug xpath, error message: Uncaught TypeError: $x is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1; It seems gmail site disabled the Console function! But how it can do that and it is possible to re-enable the Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another way to debug xpath in the console of dev tools in chrome window controlled by chromedriver in specflow

that is using javascript:

```
document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.outerHTML
```

for example:

```
document.evaluate("//a[contains(@href, 'mail.google.com') and contains(@href,'#drafts')]/../../div[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.outerHTML
```